# Flutter TextField how to detect that the text field was unfocused but not submitted?

Tags: flutter, flutter-focus-node

I want to use a `TextField` to allow the user to rename an item in the app. I would like for the new item name to be saved if the user presses the 'done' button on the keyboard but I would also like for the app to treat the user `unfocusing` the `TextField` without pressing the done button to mean the user canceled the action and the item name should be reverted to the previous name. Is there a way to call a function on unfocus only when the text was **not** submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `FocusNode` class in Flutter.

```dart
class RenameItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RenameItemWidget({required this.initialName, this.onSave});

  final String initialName;
  final void Function(String value)? onSave;

  @override
  State<RenameItemWidget> createState() => _RenameItemWidgetState();
}

class _RenameItemWidgetState extends State<RenameItemWidget> {
  late TextEditingController _textEditingController;
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  late String _itemName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialName);

    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _itemName = widget.initialName;

    _focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(RenameItemWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.initialName != widget.initialName) {
      _textEditingController.text = widget.initialName;
      _itemName = widget.initialName;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Item name'),
        onSubmitted: (_) => _saveName(),
      );

  void _onFocusChange() {
    if (!_focusNode.hasFocus && _textEditingController.text != _itemName) {
      setState(() => _textEditingController.text = _itemName);
    }
  }

  void _saveName() {
    setState(() => _itemName = _textEditingController.text);

    widget.onSave?.call(_itemName);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly was I was looking for! One thing though: It seems that when you submit, the `focusNode` listener happens before `onSave` so even though the widget was updated with the new name, the listener executed with the old `initialName` and sets the controller text to the old name. After doing a hot reload it updates properly. I fixed it by changing `widget.initalName` to `_itemName` in the listener function though you could also use `didUpdateWidget()` and set the controllet text there.